# Observe array of realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a tableview with "add exercise" button in footer view. If user tap this button, he has the option to choose an exercise. I need to store selected exercise in array (in case of user will want to display exercise details).

When user display exercise details he can also delete exercise. If user delete exercise I want to pop this view and reload table view (delete exercise from table view).

The problem is that I store selected exercises in array and I don't know how to observe (and if it is possible) array of Realm Objects.

The only solution I see is just observing all realm objects like below.

```
class WorkoutPresenter {

var notificationToken: NotificationToken?

var exercises = [Exercise]()

private func observeExercise() {
        
        notificationToken = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Exercise.self).observe({ change in
            switch change {
            case .update(let results, deletions: let deleted, insertions: _, modifications: _):
               // Here I can get deleted objects and check if it is in my array and if it is, delete exercise from exercises array and update table view.
                default:
                    break
           }
       })
    }
   }
```

I am not sure if it is correctly way to do this, because here I observe all objects, but I want to observe only selected (objects in my exercises array).

Is there any way in Realm to observe array of realm objects?

Comment: If you are storing realm objects in an array you need to reconsider your design. For your scenario, I don't understand why you don't change `exercises` to type `Results<Exercise>`. You don't need your data stored in an array.

Comment: I can't store exercises in Results, because in my array I don't store all my exercises, but only selected exercise. You can't append to results, but only to array, if I am right.

Comment: User selects exercise from tableview. When selection is done, the view is popped and I need to store this selected exercise. After that user can select next exercise, so this is the reason why I need to store it in array, because user can select few exercises.

Comment: Of course your can store one object in a Results - they work just like an array, are live updating and keep your object lazily loading. However, if this is really what you mean - *but only selected exercise* - then why not just store that one object instead of using an array (arrays are for multiple objects). Also, the question is a bit vague so maybe we are not understanding your use case; a Results should be the dataSource for your main tableView and when you open a detail view, pass in one exercise object to display the details.

Comment: @kacper99 Rather than store an exercise in the array you can store an index into the tableView. However, now that you've shared some details, you really need to update your post with some code so we can see what you're doing.